# Google Maps control missing

Tags: ios, google-maps, uiview

I added a view in the storyboard, then set the view to GMSMapView. But now the location button and compass in the map is missing. When I add the map programmatically using the instructions from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#adding_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios_to_your_project, the controls of the map appear.

.h class

```
@interface MapController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView_;

}
```

.m class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:mapView_.myLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:mapView_.myLocation.coordinate.longitude zoom:1];

    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

    mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
    mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine for me...

```
 mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapView.bounds
                                           camera:camera];
```

self.mapView is the view in storyboard. Create IBOutlet for that view

Comment: why do you need self.?

Answer (score 0):

I use these lines of code in viewDidLoad and it works properly:

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.delegate = self;
self.view = mapView_;

mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
```

Also i don't use an outlet.It doesn't needed.